# как сделать так чтобы автором коментария становился залогиненый User в django

Tags: python-3.x, django

на данный момент при создании коментария необходимо выбрать Userа, в какую степь мне копать, чтобы я смог все сделать так, чтобы автор коментария если он вошел в аккаунт автоматически становился автором коментария?
вот мой код:

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    # method adds url to redirect user after new post has been created

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})


class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.body

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})`
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin
from django.views.generic import (
    ListView,
    DetailView,
    CreateView,
    UpdateView,
    DeleteView
)
from .models import Post, Comment
from .forms import CommentForm




class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post


def add_comment(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.save()
            return redirect('post-detail',  pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    template_name = 'blog/add_comment.html'
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Comment


class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['user', 'body']
```

add_comment.html

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html'%}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}


{% block content %}

    <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">comment</legend>
                {{ form|crispy }}
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Post</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**forms**

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['body']
```

**views**

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


@login_required
def add_comment(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.user = request.user
            comment.save()
            return redirect('post-detail',  pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    template_name = 'blog/add_comment.html'
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ответ @m0nte-cr1st0 верный и хорош, но предложу и свой вариант. Он заключается в передаче в форму самого пользователя

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['body']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        self.post = kwargs.pop('post', None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self):
        if not self.user:
            raise ValidationError('No user in form')
        if not self.user.is_authenticated():
            raise ValidationError('User must be authentificated for add comment')
        if not self.post:
            raise ValidationError('Cannot add comment for non-post object')
        super().clean()


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.instance.user = self.user
        self.instance.post = self.post
        return super().save()
```

Использование

```
# Для вьюхи вроде функции
def add_comment(request, *args, **kwargs):
    post = ....
    if 'POST' in request.method:
        form = CommentForm(request.POST, post=post, user=request.user)
        if form.is_valid(): form.save()
        .....
    ...


# Для generic
class CommentView(generic.<какой удобнее будет>):
    form_class = CommentView

    def get_form_kwargs(self, *args, **kwargs):
        res = super().get_form_kwargs(*args, **kwargs)
        res['user'] = self.request.user
        res['post'] = ... #код поиска поста
        retur res
```

В моем случае, проверкой данных занимается сама форма

Comment: если CRUD функционал для родительского поста реализован с помощью CBV то есть ли разница как реализовать комментарии( используя Class Based Views или в виде Функций)?

Comment: Если по ajax будете подгружать, то думаю CBV удобнее, ибо оба метода в одном месте: GET для получения, POST для добавления, удаления. Функции тоже хорошо, но больше писать придется и не так красиво. Да и лучше не мешать стилистику кода, а то потом галза будут вытекать